# screen goes black while watching videos despite settings

Tags: 16.04, unity, crouton

ok so i'm running xenial with unity on my chromebook via crouton and the chromeos power setting is set to never go dark, and the power settings in the ubuntu are set to never go dark, but after a couple minutes of video (netflix in google-chrome) the screen goes dark. why is this? how do i stop it?

Comment: Does the "couple minutes" correspond to when the screen saver would trigger? If so try disabling the screen saver.

Comment: there is no screensaver installed in ubuntu

Comment: Could be power saving is enabled.  What does the command `xset -q | awk '/DPMS is/ {print $NF}'` return?

Comment: i ran the command and it didnt return anything at all

Comment: Could you try to install ffmpeg by running this command line `apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg` ?